# Torque measurement device calibration

Tags: measurement, device, calibration, torque

I don't know if I'm at the right place to ask this question but here is my trouble :

I'm trying to find a good way of calibrating a electronic device used to measure small torques (0 -> 25 mNm).

Device adjustment :
Our current way of adjusting our measuring device is by hanging measurement standards to it and adjusting the way it measures.

Calibration :
Our current way of calibrating this device is again by hanging the measurement standards and checking if the device measures properly.

Being new to the process of calibrating a device, is there a standard way of proceeding ? Are there good documentations on the calibration problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calibration of equipment in manufacturing and other professional environments, when done "by the book", is governed by ISO 17025. This not only governs the procedures and methodologies, it includes things such as labeling and  traceability. This standard should be a good starting point for your research into calibration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I'll give it a serious look !